# Is there anything wrong with the folowing phrase: "Man [placeholder] is so awesome, being awestruck at every minute!"

Tags: grammar, phrases, punctuation

I'm not very familiar with how punctuation works in the English language so that is a big problem for me when trying to form a phrase like that, any other mistakes you could point out would be much appreciated.

Comment: Being awestruck does not make one awesome.  One is awestruck ***by*** awesome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Man, Mark is so awesome! I am awestruck by the minute!

Or

Man, Mark is so awesome; I am awestruck by the minute!

Comment: Any reason you chose those punctuation marks?